# CocoaPods integration

Tags: objective-c, ios8, afnetworking, cocoapods

I have integrated cocoapods for AFNetworking library for the very first time.

followed instructions from http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2 link.

My workspace created fine. I have opened workspace and not the xcode project. Still getting below 4 errors(attached screenshot) [image]. Don't know what I have done wrong.

Any help is really appreciable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Man the screenshot resolution is too little, i can't read it.

Comment: Delete your DerivedData folder ( ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData ) & then try..

Comment: @jalone : Now is it visible?

Comment: @NileshPatel : Deleted derived data, still getting same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update Xcode recently? If so, clean your build folder and delete the derived data. Then build your project again.

If you have set the

> Target > Build Settings > Build Active Architecture Only

setting on the debug configuration. That may be the problem. Try to set it to YES. Clean and build!

Hope that helps.

**Edit:**

If your **Architectures & Valid Architectures** are all right, you may check whether you have add **$(inherited)** to **Other Linker Flags** as below.

[image]

Alternatively you can set **Architectures** to **armv7 armv7s**.

Comment: may I see the content of project's pod file otherwise you can add the below line at the end of your pod file and again run the command "pod install". 
link_with 'targetName'

Comment: Added that line and install it again. Still having same problem. :(
Hey, I have one query. There is one folder "Pods" inside project. I have one old project in which pods are working fine, so I just checked that there are three files under "Pods" folder and in my current project there are only two.
Don't know what impact it may create to my project.

Comment: Not added $(inherited). Should I add it?

Comment: Yes u should add this.

Comment: Yeahhhhhh......!!!!!!!!!!!!! Big big big thanks to you.. You have solved my problem. Thanks a lot..!!!!
Sorry I cant vote you up. because don't have that much credits. :p